# Apache wont load website when multiple downloads are running

Tags: server, apache2, webdav

I set up a webdav to share files, when downloading multiple files (6) and I try to open the website its just loading constantly until a download is finished. The website will then open instantly. I couldn't find an option in the apache2.conf. I am sorry if this issue was already documented, I was unable to find it though..

My server: Apache/2.4.18 on xenial with all packages up-to-date. I am using Digest Auth over HTTPS with a valid certificate. This is my [apache2.conf](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24948611)

Edit: while downloading 6 files I tried opening the web page in another browser (I usually use FF, now Chrome on top and it loads instantly but only gives me gibberish (this is the content of the webpage):

```
‹Í”QoÚ0Çßû)n~˜¶‡Ä!À¨¨ã‰¦"Q@…jš¦=8±C¼%väºîÓÏLe¨Ýžúä‹ó»óÿqŽ¼Šãõçå®×73XÞ}˜MÇ€<Œ?uÇÇë¸yÑõCø(+0žÌ½ ¹-z$Œ»ˆ•¶tª¸ø:|/Îv7ûŽÄ-JÍö:'h·y(Æ’CÒ>4”Øv¬!«+D‰,7P›4BX¦ZÕ8)˜úîod†€6B_¦ãÅWÇa›ï³)a‘Eèý8š_-¢Ñ9+Áì4sã˜¢3V[(5—™ü,¼jà•üy¾`Ü0±¨S#++µzD±³xl5ÕE]1çµïäæ˜jþT7XúG3–£ÛÉ|Oo›–ð}‰GuÑ%3BYˆ¥©Õæ¡ÕÖ€¯URWW¿¡=ÙÈMnðà$ùr3]paŽŸ“:R²No³«üKVt^ðÎûÃ°ð"ôÇzûMºwÚèI}/@çrt_ˆ‡kwS˜tÚà9_aAwØü§ƒgþ¸„qnD]ÓQÅÒ\àÐïùKxs—l•Ý¾…•0;a€YH¶Ï ¥P~ªKXjc¡×ë:GmWô0¬Ü\:Œ»_þ!i.
```

Accessing the webdav is on is working fine in Chrome (while downloading 6 files from webdav) but I cant open any webdav page, it returns gibberish like that up there.

Comment: Paste your `apache2.conf` content here (http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and then give a link in the post. This will help to check your present configuration.

Comment: this is my apache2.conf. I think I never touched it. https://paste.ubuntu.com/24948611/